# Signature for matrix-vector product function

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, signature

I am relatively new to C++ and still confused how to pass and return arrays as arguments. I would like to write a simple matrix-vector-product `c = A * b` function, with a signature like

```
times(A, b, c, m, n)
```

where `A` is a two-dimensional array, `b` is the input array, `c` is the result array, and `m` and `n` are the dimensions of `A`. I want to specify array dimensions through `m` and `n`, not through `A`.

The body of the (parallel) function is

```
int i, j;
double sum;

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i, j, sum) shared(m, n, A, b, c)
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    sum = 0.0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        sum += A[i][j] * b[j];
    }
    c[i] = sum;
}
```

1. What is the correct signature for a function like this?
2. Now suppose I want to create the result array c in the function and return it. How can I do this?

Comment: In order to be able to write `c = A * b;`, you'll need a `Vector operator*(const Matrix& A, const Vector& b);` or similar (depending on what your matrix and vector classes are, if they're templates, etc...). You could also make it a member function of the matrix class (thus getting the matrix argument implicitly, so the signature omits the first argument).

Comment: Use `std::array<std::array, width>, height>` (or whatever your row/column order preferences are) instead of simple C-style arrays. You could also use `std::vector` if you wanted the ability to resize at runtime. You can pass `std::array` instances into and return from functions without any particular effort.

Comment: @Rook: C-style arrays don't take any particular effort either.

Comment: @twalberg An operator would be elegant, but that's not what I was asking for. A simple function is enough for the moment.

Comment: @Rook: Can you write out the signature using std::array? What do i need to import to use std::array?

Comment: @CareyGregory a couple of issues spring to mind... `int a[2]` is not an lvalue, and I don't believe you can return C-arrays of explicit fixed length from a function, only a pointer. The standard containers do not have this issue, equipped as they are with appropriate copy and move constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of "you should rather" answer (which I will leave up, because you really should rather!), here is "what you asked for" answer.

I would use `std::vector` to hold your array data (because they have O(1) move capabilities) rather than a `std::array` (which saves you an indirection, but costs more to move around).  `std::vector` is the C++ "improvement" of a `malloc`'d (and `realloc`'d) buffer, while `std::array` is the C++ "improvement" of a `char foo[27];` style buffer.

```
std::vector<double> times(std::vector<double> const& A, std::vector<double> const& b, size_t m, size_t n)
{
  std::vector<double> c;
  Assert(A.size() = m*n);
  c.resize(n);

  // .. your code goes in here.
  // Instead of A[x][y], do A[x*n+y] or A[y*m+x] depending on if you want column or
  // row-major order in memory.
  return std::move(c); // O(1) copy of the std::vector out of this function
}
```

You'll note I changed the signature slightly, so that it returns the std::vector instead of taking it as a parameter.  I did this because I can, and it looks prettier!

If you really must pass `c` in to the function, pass it in as a `std::vector<double>&` -- a reference to a `std::vector`.

Comment: Shouldn't `A` be of type `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`?

Comment: `std::move` is a C++11 feature which I cannot use. How should the return statement look like instead?

Comment: @cls you could do as he says and pass in the vector by reference, which would also look more like your original intent

Comment: Do you know how to look at a flat array of values as a two dimensional array?  See the comment above in the code where I say "instead of A[x][y]".  A std::vector of std::vector does not use continguous memory.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer you should use...  So a good way to solve this one involves creating a `struct` or `class` to wrap your array (well, buffer of data -- I'd use a `std::vector`).  And instead of a signature like `times(A, b, c, m, n)`, go with this kind of syntax:

```
Matrix<4,4> M;
ColumnMatrix<4> V;
ColumnMatrix<4> C = M*V;
```

where the width/height of M are in the `<4,4>` numbers.

A quick sketch of the Matrix class might be (somewhat incomplete -- no const access, for example)

```
template<size_t rows, size_t columns>
class Matrix
{
private:
  std::vector<double> values;
public:
  struct ColumnSlice
  {
    Matrix<rows,columns>* matrix;
    size_t row_number;
    double& operator[](size_t column) const
    {
      size_t index = row_number * columns + column;
      Assert(matrix && index < matrix->values.size());
      return matrix->values[index];
    }
    ColumnSlice( Matrix<rows,columns>* matrix_, size_t row_number_ ):
      matrix(matrix_), row_number(row_number_)
    {}
  };
  ColumnSlice operator[](size_t row)
  {
    Assert(row < rows); // note: zero based indexes
    return ColumnSlice(this, row);
  }
  Matrix() {values.resize(rows*columns);}
  template<size_t other_columns>
  Matrix<rows, other_columns> operator*( Matrix<columns, other_columns> const& other ) const
  {
    Matrix<rows, other_columns> retval;
    // TODO: matrix multiplication code goes here
    return std::move(retval);
  }
};

template<size_t rows>
using ColumnMatrix = Matrix< rows, 1 >;

template<size_t columns>
using RowMatrix = Matrix< 1, columns >;
```

The above uses C++0x features your compiler might not have, and can be done without these features.

The point of all of this?  You can have math that both looks like math and does the right thing in C++, while being really darn efficient, and *that* is the "proper" C++ way to do it.

You can also program in a C-like way using some features of C++ (like `std::vector` to handle array memory management) if you are more used to it.  But that is a different answer to this question.  :)

(Note: code above has not been compiled, nor is it a complete Matrix implementation.  There are template based Matrix implementations in the wild you can find, however.)

Comment: This looks like a good long-term solution: A proper Matrix/Vector class with operators. For the moment, though, I'd only like to know the signature for the function above, provided there can be one. From what I've read so far, I shouldn't use C-style arrays at all, but `std::array`.

Comment: @cls Any time you think to yourself `For the moment, ...` that automatically means that if you don't do it correctly now you'll be stuck with a suboptimal solution forever.

Comment: @cls in this case, `std::array` and `std::vector` are more or less interchangeable. The principle benefit of `std::array` is that you can explicitly define its size in a function parameter. If the container is already wrapped up in a class, the distinction is much less important.

Comment: @Mark B: Most of the time, you'd be right, but this is one of the situations in which I really don't need a solution as complex as yours.

Comment: Created second answer, but I'm so leaving this one up.  You really should rather use this one.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Normal vector-matrix multiplication is as follows:

```
friend Vector operator*(const Vector &v, const Matrix &m);
```

But if you want to pass the dimensions separately, it's as follows:

```
friend Vector mul(const Vector &v, const Matrix &m, int size_x, int size_y);
```

Since the Vector and Matrix would be 1d and 2d arrays, they would look like this:

```
struct Vector { float *array; };
struct Matrix { float *matrix; };
```